# BQ grouping tables differently

Tags: google-bigquery

When my table names are
table_20160101, table_20150101 and table_20140101, In the BQ UI i see BQ grouping these tables as table_(3).

When my table names are table_2016, table_2015 and table_2014, BQ doesn't group them.

Any particular reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

BQ Web UI groups tables with below pattern

```
TableNameYYYYMMDD into group named TableName(count#)
```

I think that major motivation was to support "daily tables partitioning" design pattern, where you can have hundreds and hundreds of daily table occupying Web UI real-estate.  Should be yearly and monthly partitioning considered. I think it was just least used pattern and in any case it is less issue from real-estate prospective when you have 10 or so yearly tables

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Is there a way to group tables with table_YYYY? I mean do i need to any configuration changes.

Comment: from what I know  - there is no any options to set custom grouping in GBQ Web UI. The only that is supported is for pattern as TableYYYYMMDD

Comment: Correct, we only support TableYYYYMMDD right now, since that's the pattern expected by TABLE_DATE_RANGE (and is therefore quite common). https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions